# Resource Not found, when calling create campaign API

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

I am using linkedIn ad campaign API, I am facing an issue in create campaign api.
I am getting 404 response code ""message": "No virtual resource found""
API URL: https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAccounts/%7B%60adAccountId%60%7D/adCampaigns
payload

I am passing same value in `sponsoredaccount_id` and `adAccountId`

I am excepting get correct response after calling API

Comment: That URL decodes to `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAccounts/{\`adAccountId\`}/adCampaigns`. If that's the URL you're actually trying to visit, then learly that's not the correct URL. Have you got something which is supposed to substitute `{\`adAccountId\`}` for a real value? Is it not doing so? It's a bit unclear what is actually happening. See [ask] and then [edit] your post to clarify it a bit

Comment: I am passing same ad account id in adAccountId and sponsoredaccount_id, Please check the screenshot. https://prnt.sc/txp-rdUwcb37. from my point point of view adAccountId is incorrect. I am not able to find that what is correct value there

Comment: From the screenshot I can't see what exact URL it actually ended up calling, nor can I see the values of the variables you're using the URL or the request body.

Comment: adAccountId  512293020 , campaigngroup_id1 666860473, sponsoredaccount_id 512293020 , baseurl: https://api.linkedin.com/rest